# How to port a compiled code for Maemo 5 into Symbian Anna devices?

Tags: symbian, maemo

I've compiled code of Maemo 5. How would I port it to Symbian Anna device? How do I compile the same code for Symbian Anna device? Any hints/articles related to it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - rewrite it in Symbian or Qt.
If you really want it then read [this link](http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=42399).